# React Typescript: Problem when i try to send history argument from a component to an action using withRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I use ReactJS + Typescript

In the Login.tsx component, when the user presses the login button, I want to call an action (I use redux-thunk) with the history parameter from the react router dom.

When I export the Login.tsx component using the withRouter function  in order to access the history, I get the following warning:
'Argument of type 'ComponentClass , any> & WithRouterStatics > 'is not assignable to parameter of type' ComponentType

And at the line where i call the action "loginUser" i get the error: "Expected 1 arguments, but got 2."

I don't know how to send the history parameter using withRouter in a proper way, if someone has a solution for this would be gret, thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Here is the code for Login.tsx component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";
import { loginUser } from "../../actions/user";
import { AppState } from "../../reducers/rootReducer";
import styles from "./Login.module.css";

export interface FormLoginInput {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

type IProps =  RouteComponentProps & {
  loading: boolean;
  loginUser: (formLoginInput: FormLoginInput) => React.ReactNode;
  message: string | null | undefined;
  errors: [] | null | undefined;
  error: boolean;
}

const Login: React.FC<IProps> = ({ loading, message, errors, error, loginUser, history }): JSX.Element => {
  const [formInput, setFormInput] = useState<FormLoginInput>({
    email: "",
    password: ""
  });

  const { email, password } = formInput;

  const handleSubmitLogin = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(formInput);
    console.log(history);
    loginUser(formInput, history);
  }

  return (
    <form className={styles.form} onSubmit={handleSubmitLogin}>
      <h1 className={styles.formTitle}>login</h1>
      <p className={styles.formDesc}>Login Here For Using Our Features</p>
      <div className={styles.formInput}>
        <input 
          type="text" 
          placeholder="Enter Email..."
          name="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setFormInput({ ...formInput, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
      <div className={styles.formInput}>
        <input 
          type="password" 
          placeholder="Enter Password..."
          name="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setFormInput({ ...formInput, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })}  
        />
      </div>
      <input className={styles.formBtn} type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => ({
  message: state.user.message,
  errors: state.user.errors,
  error: state.user.error,
  loading: state.user.loading
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { loginUser })(withRouter(Login));
```

And the imported action "loginUser" that i want to call with history argument:

```
export const loginUser = (formLoginInput: FormLoginInput, history: any) => async (dispatch: Dispatch<IAction>): Promise<any> => {
  const { email, password } = formLoginInput;
  const body: string = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

  try {
    const response: AxiosResponse<any> = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/auth/login", body, config);
    response.data.message = "Login with success!";

    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_USER,
      data: response.data
    });
    history.push("/user/dashboard");
  } catch(error) {
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_ERROR, 
      data: error.response.data
    });
    console.error(error.message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `compose`

```
import { compose } from 'redux';



export default compose(
    withRouter,
    connect(mapStateToProps, { loginUser } )(Login)
);
```